# Laravel 5 url localized, with subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, routes, internationalization

Let's say I have a multilang website, localized with subdomain.

I would like to localize urls in this way:

```
en.site.com/images
it.site.com/immagini
fr.site.com/metaphorik
es.site.com/imágenes
```

How can I achive this with laravel? Note I know i can do:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{lang}.myapp.com'), function() {

});
```

But how can I localize urls ?

Comment: Not overly simply. if you don't have many pages and all your URIs are not dynamic (i.e. editable in a CMS or something) then you could do it a couple of ways: 1. store routes in a configuration file and generate the routes dynamically by iterating through and using trans() to get the translated versions. 2. Set routes up like `Route::get('{page}')` and making the closure/controller action that accepts this route do some magic to look up the correct page based on the given subdomain. But yeah, it's not really well-supported, and, if I'm honest, it'd be difficult for Laravel to do so.

Comment: wow that's really a hard limit, could we issue a ticket on github?

Comment: You certainly can, but you'd probably need to at least start thinking of a potential way for it to be implemented if you want the ticket to get any kind of positive response. As I said in my comment above, it's not a simple thing to solve. For people with very fixed URIs then yeah it's not too difficult to add something in to support that (but then again you can do it relatively easily following my two options above anyway), and anyone with any slightly complex URI system will have such specific use-cases that I'd bet a generic solution is far from easy to implement and then use.

Comment: I know it's kinda late... but for people in the future. I had the exact same problem so I decided to create my own package for it. For people having the same problem, have a look https://github.com/pmochine/Laravel-Tongue